# python re.findall() with substring in alternations

Tags: python, regex

If I have a substring (or 'subpattern') of another string or pattern in a regex alternation, like so:

```
r'abcd|bc'
```

What is the expected behaviour of `re.compile(r'abcd|bc').findall('abcd bcd bc ab')`?

Trying it out, I get (as expected)

```
['abcd', 'bc', 'bc']
```

so I thought `re.compile(r'bc|abcd').findall('abcd bcd bc ab')` might yield `['bc', 'bc', 'bc']` but instead it again returns

```
['abcd', 'bc', 'bc']
```

Can someone explain this? I was under the impression that `findall` would greedily return matches but apparently, it backtracks and tries to match alternate patterns what would yield longer tokens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No backtracking takes place *at all*. Your pattern matches two different types of strings; `|` means *or*. Each pattern is tried out at each position.

So when the expression finds `abcd` at the start of your input, that text matches your pattern just fine, it fits the `abcd` part of the (`bc` *or* `abcd`) pattern you gave it.

Ordering of the alternative parts doesn't play here, as far as the regular expression engine is concerned, `abcd|bc` is the *same thing* as `bc|abcd`. `abcd` is not disregarded just because `bc` might match later on in the string.