# Python's regex '|' (or) operator

Tags: python, regex

According to Python's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) for regular expression syntax for `|` (or) operator: "...once A matches, B will not be tested further, even if it would produce a longer overall match. In other words, the '|' operator is never greedy."

I have tried this in my console (running Python 3.7.6):

```
import re
txt = 'tim is walking and tom is running'
pattern = 'tim|tom'
re.findall(pattern, txt)
```

and I get:

```
['tim', 'tom']
```

Why is the right side of `|` still evaluated in this case?

Comment: It's finding all instances that match the pattern `tim|tom`, try `re.match(pattern, txt)` which just captures `tim`

Comment: Because `re.findall` finds all non-overlapping occurrences of a pattern  in a string. `re.search` finds the first one.

Comment: It comes into play when looking at any individual match. Try `walk|walking`. You'll always get `walk` back, never `walking`, even though `walking` is longer.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Please re-close the question. At least with [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/).  This question is a result of misunderstanding regex and `re.findall`. [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python) is a **valid** close reason for this question

Comment: So, use [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean). This question is a result of misunderstanding regex and `re.findall`. [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python) is a **valid** close reason for this question

Comment: Do any of those discuss the non-greediness of `|`?

Comment: `|` has nothing to do with greediness, it is not a quantifier. The `|` operator is also thoroughly discussed in [Order of regular expression operator (..|.. … ..|..)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606426/order-of-regular-expression-operator). This question is not asking about this `|` operator peculiarity.

Comment: It *could* be greedy but it's not. Greediness *is* a possible adjective. Read the first paragraph of this question--the (non-) greediness of `|` is exactly what the question is about.

Comment: Greedy or non-greedy terms only relate to quantifiers, not alternation operator. **The question is about why two matches are returned.** - The answer: ***Because `re.findall` returns all of them.***

Comment: Wiktor, the question is about both of those things. It's about the `|` operator *and* it's about `findall()`. The OP thinks they're related. It turns out they're orthogonal features. A good answer should explain both the quoted excerpt in the first paragraph and what `findall()` does, and why they're different. I've been trying to think about how to word such an answer; it's tricky and I haven't figured it out yet.

Comment: John, so add [BOTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4697882/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-python) the [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35606426/order-of-regular-expression-operator) as close reasons, just what I tried to do but failed since you rushed to reopen the post.

Comment: @JohnKugelman What about [python re.findall() with substring in alternations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20647431/python-re-findall-with-substring-in-alternations)?

Comment: Thank you for these comments gentlemen. I would encourage to keep this question open. I know that reading more material online could have answered my question, but at times it helps a human take a look at your code an explain why it is not working. Thanks again!